# C# Unit Test for Android Class Library (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Using MS VS15 and Xamarin, I have an Class Library (Android) that contains a mix of plain C# and a linked Library Binding (embedded jar) project.
I wish to unit test this, and will be mocking the Library Binding element (although I do have to pass in the Activity, can be null for tests), so in reality I am unit testing plain non-Android C# code.

It appears I needed to create a 'Unit Test App (Android)' Test project, but this now runs all unit tests on the device/emulator.

Question: Is there a way to run plain C# unit tests against the Android Class Library and avoid running up the emulator?

Comment: Short answer: No.  If you need access to the Android classes, you need an Android OS to run them on as they are Java-based so you need an ART/Dalvik runtime and the Xamarin-Java bridge. You have to totally separate/isolate your "pure" C# from your `Xamarin.Android` based C#, as soon as you start pulling in `Android.` namespaces you need to test on a device/emulator.

Comment: You can only define a PCL class library, or .NET Core class library (with Xamarin's latest beta channel). Then such class library can be unit tested on desktop.